# grep vector from multile column in df and print column nth in R

Tags: r

I need to match a vector of pattern from df3$end to df2$V2 and df$V3. Then final outfile should take df1 and append the matched columns V4 and V5 from df2 as shown in expected output.

```
    df1 <- read.table(text='  chr    init
12  25289552
                  3 180418785
                  3 180434779
                  6 69909
                  5 284892182', header=TRUE)


df2 <- read.table(text='    V1    V2  V3  V4  V5  V6
                  1     69094   321233  medium  2.1   321234
                  1     69094 21231310  medium  3.4 21231313
                  12 25289552 180434559  high  1.1 180434779
                  1     69095 69909 medium  2.9 69909
                  3 180418785 284892182 medium  1.8 284892182
                  3 180434779 69909 low 2.8 69909', header=TRUE)

df3 <- read.table(text='  chr    init end
 12  25289552 180434779
                  3 180418785 321233
                  3 180434779 180434779
                  6 69909     69909
                  5 284892182 21231313
                  3 180418785 284892182 ', header=TRUE)
#expected output

df1_chr    df1_init df3_end  df2_V4 df2_V5 df2_V4_2 df2_V5_2
12  25289552 180434779 high  1.1 NA NA NA
3 180418785 321233  medium  2.1 284892182 medium     1.8 
3 180434779 180434779  high  1.1 NA NA NA
6 69909 69909 medium/low  2.9/2.8 NA NA NA
5 284892182 21231313  medium  3.4 NA NA NA
```

I tried:

```
matches <- filter(df2, grepl(paste(df3$end, collapse="|"), df2$V3,df2$V4))
```

This gives the matched rows. Now I need to take df1 and add the matching end column from df3, V4 and V5 from df2 to the output. In case df1_init has different df3_ends then have to add them as separate columns, as shown in example. Any help to achieve the final output is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can u use dplyr?

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
inner_join(df3, by=c("chr","init")) %>% 
inner_join(df2,by=c("end"="V3")) %>% 
select(-V1,-V2) %>% group_by(chr,init,end) %>% 
summarise(df2_V4 = paste(V4,collapse=","),df2_V5 = paste(V5,collapse=","))
```

Comment: Is it possible to inner_join by "end" = 2 different columns, like in V3 or V6 in df2 (by=c("end"="V3 V6"), didn't work). Also in few cases df1_init has different df3_ends, so have to add them as separate columns, as shown in edited example. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.